# How to set a base url for react-router at the app level?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, create-react-app, base-url

I have an app created with create-react-app that I want to install in a subdirectory on my website. The recommended way is to add `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` as the baseurl. ie:

```
<Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/signin`} component={SigninPage}/>
```

Now is there a way I can set it at the app level so I don't have to duplicate this piece of code on every Routes or Links or NavLinks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

You can set it as `basename` on your `Router`, here are links to the react router docs: [`basename` in `BrowserRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) and [`basename` in `HashRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter/basename-string). It would look something like this:

```
<Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
</Router>
```

Comment: How should we write link path in href?

Answer (score 0):

With React Router v6, it is recommended to use [`createBrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.14.2/routers/create-browser-router) for web projects.

Pass an options object as the second argument to `createBrowserRouter`  to configure the [`basename`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.14.2/routers/create-browser-router#basename).

```
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    /* routes... */
], { basename: process.env.PUBLIC_URL });

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```