# react router relative path to static files not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router, relative-path

I have a react app (simple frontend app) that in production is on a relative path (for instance suite.app.com/auth). Other apps are on different paths. So I need all requests for static files for this app to be routed via nginx to /auth. Basically this works fine from an nginx perspective but from a react perspective I need the paths to be relative:

In my package.json I have added `"homepage": "./",`

and in my index.html I have added `<base href="/auth/">`

So now when I load the files, I can see in the network tab of browser
[image]

which is what I expect. Static files relative. However in my server logs when I load the app I can  see this occuring:

[image]

I.e *something* is not passing the request to the correct path. (FWIW the reason they are coming back with 200's there, is because there is a different app on the root so its actually loading the other apps files, not this ones.

Any tips of what might be occuring here would be great.

EDIT: Posting the Nginx config for the two endpoints. The

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app.site.com;
    add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'origin';
    location /auth {
        proxy_pass http://authentication.internal.app/;
        proxy_set_header Host authentication.internal.app;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://dashboard.internal.app/;
        proxy_set_header Host dashboard.internal.app;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48134785/how-to-set-a-base-url-for-react-router-at-the-app-level ?

Comment: Your Nginx config is wrong. Please post your location directives.

Comment: @miknik have posted nginx. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify a `proxy_pass` directive then if you append anything to the end of the base URL Nginx will replace the portion of the original client request URL which matches your location block with whatever you have added to the `proxy_pass` URL.

So in your case you have `location /auth` and then `proxy_pass http://authentication.internal.app/` with an all important trailing slash

So a client request to `example.com/auth/static/style.css` matches the location block `/auth`, Nginx drops `/auth` and replaces it with `/` and now your proxy is getting `proxy.server//static/style.css`

If you drop the slash to change your `proxy_pass` directive to `proxy_pass http://authentication.internal.app` the entire client request URL will be passed to the proxy, so the above request will be proxied to `proxy.server/auth/static/style.css`. For the opposite effect, leave the `proxy_pass` value as it is and change the location block to `location /auth/` and Nginx will now replace `/auth/` with `/` and the proxied request will become `proxy.server/static/style.css`

Purely for readability I would swap the order of your location directives in your config file so that the first entry is `location /`

It's a common misconception that Nginx evaluates location directives in the order they are listed and chooses the first match, but this is only true for locations defined by regular expressions.

All prefix matches are evaluated regardless of the order they are listed and Nginx selects the longest matching prefix location. The request is now evaluated against all location blocks containing regular expressions, this part does happen in the order they are listed, and if any of them match Nginx will immediately forget the longest prefix location and pass the request to the matching regex location. If none match then the best prefix match will handle the request.

You can prevent Nginx for searching for regex matches for requests matching a certain prefix location by adding the `^~` modifier before the location.

Obviously there are no regex locations in your current config so a lot of this is not relevant right now, but if you go down that route later it's not exactly intuitive so maybe it'll come in helpful at some point.

Comment: Thanks yeah so it worked when I set the location to `/auth/`